# Islamic standing on a 20-year-old male living with much older female?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, men-women

I am a 20-year-old male and I have a much older female friend (early 60s) who is getting divorced. I would like to offer her a room in my house until she gets back on her feet.

I would appreciate any help in determining the legal (Islamic) standing of this. Any reading material/evidence would be really helpful.

Comment: there is quran 24:60 as an argument to support the position that it is ok.

Comment: I think this should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

If she is just a friend it is ok to help her as she would be like your mother or older sister. If you are having sexual relations with her, or even fantasizing about it, then there in nothing that would help you or support your sinful way. Stop it right away and ask for forgiveness.

Answer (score -1):

If there's no other married couple, female, her family to do this then you must do this, she's is Muslima and needs the support from other Muslims. If you don't support her then who will?!

I doubt what Shakir has said in his answer is what you're thinking of, but if that's the case then you should avoid it. Very likely she's a women of  qdinar has mentioned in the comment and you should be fine. She's like your grandmother...

And women of post-menstrual age who have no desire for marriage - there is no blame upon them for putting aside their outer garments [but] not displaying adornment. But to modestly refrain [from that] is better for them. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.https://quran.com/24/60